# Infinite Loop of Images using React and Firestore Database - How do I get my data?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am very new to react and I am working with firestore database and react. Currently, I am trying to display information from a nested collection. When I run my app I get an infinite loop of my image. I been trying different ways to get my information but I keep coming across errors. What I am doing wrong to cause this infinite loop and how can I successfully render my information. Thanks !
[my database][1]

````
import {firebaseLooper} from '../tools/firebaselooper';
import { usersCollection } from '../tools/firebase';
import { AuthContext } from "./AuthConnect";

const ViewOneAdventure = (props) => {
    const {currentUser, userDetails} = useContext(AuthContext);
    const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
    const currentLocationId = props.location.state.id

    useEffect(() => {
        //const unmount = 
        usersCollection
        .doc(currentUser.uid)
        .collection('locations')
        .doc(currentLocationId)
        .collection('dates')
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                setResults([...results,doc.data()])
            });
        });
    });

        return(
            <div>
            <p>
            
            {results.map((result) => (
            <aside key={result.day}>
            <aside src={result.journalentry} />
            <img src={result.travelphotos} 
                alt="image">
            </img>
            </aside>
       ))}
       </p>
            </div>
        )
}
export default ViewOneAdventure;   ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkjL8.png
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `useEffect` is missing the dependency array so it's running each render cycle, and since it updates state, it triggers another render cycle. Add a dependency array.

Use an empty dependency array to run once when the component mounts:

```
useEffect(() => {
  usersCollection
    .doc(currentUser.uid)
    .collection('locations')
    .doc(currentLocationId)
    .collection('dates')
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            setResults([...results,doc.data()])
        });
    });
}, []); // <-- empty dependency array to run once on mount
```

Or more likely you want the `currentUser.uid` as a dependency to run the effect on mount and when `currentUser.uid` updates:

```
useEffect(() => {
  usersCollection
    .doc(currentUser.uid)
    .collection('locations')
    .doc(currentLocationId)
    .collection('dates')
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            setResults([...results,doc.data()])
        });
    });
}, [currentUser.uid]); // *
```

***** add any missing dependencies any linters complain about, like maybe `currentLocationId`. It depends on what and when you want to update the `results` state.

Answer (score 1):

You are updating using `useState` inside an `useEffect` with out passing any dependencies. This provokes an infinite loop. Please include `[]` or `["your dependencies"]` after the `useEffect`. For example like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  usersCollection
    .doc(currentUser.uid)
    .collection('locations')
    .doc(currentLocationId)
    .collection('dates')
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            setResults([...results,doc.data()])
        });
    });
}, [currentUser.uid]);
```